# MPEG-DASH cross-browser play

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, streaming, mpeg-dash

I want to stream some video file and i've found interesting the DASH adaptive streaming capabilities, but i'cant find anything else but "dash.js" (which seems to work only for Chrome browsers) to implement client-side playback (integrated with html5 "video" tag). I know that dash.js works with chrome's mediasource APIs, but -if i'm not wrong- they should be standardized by W3C. Firefox [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DASH_Adaptive_Streaming_for_HTML_5_Video) that MSE APIs are already avaliable on the recent versions, but [dashif.org example video](http://dashif.org/reference/players/javascript/0.2.5/index.html) doesn't work, while an alert says that i should retry with chrome. So, what can a poor student at first experience with web development do to adaptive-stream video with html5???

Comment: it says right on the page you link to that "As of 7/11/13, Chrome and Internet Explorer 11 are the only browsers supported." I encourage you to use a better format instead of a big $tudio draconian hollywood-backed codec that only for-profit content-owning browser makers support...

Comment: Many thanks dan! However, streaming fails in IE too...so, can i ask here for alternative formats that enable me to do the same thing?

Comment: Apple's HLS and many flash products are viable alternatives

Comment: yes, we took into account Flash-based solutions but, first and foremost, we are planning to develop the whole front end with htlm5/css3/javascript. Should i give up on it?

Comment: there is no HTML5 silver bullet for streaming video. yet.

Comment: Firefox has a whitelist for dash support (youtube, netflix, and one other?), but plans to get rid of the white list in the next few releases, which I assume means open dash support to all.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=778617#c73

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, Firefox supports the standardized Media Source Extensions, but you also need to confirm that the content you are trying to play is supported in terms of video and audio codecs.

You can find the supported codecs for Firefox [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats). So, the key for cross-browser compatibility is to use the audio and video codecs supported by all browsers.

Also, there is a much newer version of the DASH.js player currently available, perhaps you want to give it a try: [DASH.js 1.1.2](http://dashif.org/reference/players/javascript/1.1.2/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can test the MSE implementation of Firefox already with the developer version of Firefox 36/37. Please not that you have to enable it via about:config. Currently it is planned to release it in version 37, to the best of my knowledge. Also the nightly build allows MSE testing.

According to your player request, I can recommend the player from [www.dash-player.com](http://www.dash-player.com). I tested it already on IE 11 (Win 8), Safari 8, Firefox 36 and Chrome (Windows, Linux, Android) of course. They have also an automatic fallback solution using Flash. And, perfectly for students - it's free.